# Cross-browser keyboard event handler

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, keyboard-events

I have a keypress handler that I borrowed that used to work across browsers but now no longer works on webkit browsers.  Can anyone offer suggestions how to fix?

Here is the handler:

```
function handleKeys(e) {
    //credit: http://santrajan.blogspot.com/2007/03/cross-browser-keyboard-handler.html
    var character;
    var evt = (e) ? e : window.event;       //IE reports window.event not arg
    if (evt.type == "keydown") {
        character = evt.keycode;
        if (character < 16 ||                    // non printables
            (character > 16 && character < 32) ||     // avoid shift
            (character > 32 && character < 41) ||     // navigation keys
            character == 46) {                   // Delete Key (Add to these if you need)
            handleNonChar(character);            // function to handle non Characters
            nonChar = true;
        } else
            nonChar = false;
    } else {                                // This is keypress
        if (nonChar) return;                // Already Handled on keydown
        character = (evt.charCode) ?
                   evt.charCode : evt.keyCode;
        if (character > 31 && character < 256)        // safari and opera
            handleChar(character);               //
    }
}
```

The handler is called in the pages like this:

```
<script>
document.onkeydown = function(e) {handleKeys(e)}
document.onkeypress = function(e) {handleKeys(e)}
var nonChar = false;
</script>
```

Thanks!

Tim

Comment: Works for me (Chrome), except that you haven't posted `handleNonChar`/`handleChar`: http://jsfiddle.net/eXYdV/.

Comment: Have you tried if jQuery .keypresS() works on webkit browsers? If it does i would use that.

Comment: I think pimvdb is on to something--I realized there was no handleNonChar() defined which stopped Webkit but Mozilla apparently ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If you pair up a JS Library that will normalize the charCode/keyCode differences, and use it in conjunction with a plugin dedicated to keyboard input you should make out quite well.

I've used [jQuery](http://www.jQuery.com/) with [HotKeys Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/snippets-4-all/). However you can also use the [shortcut keyboard handling](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/) without jQuery (which the HotKeys Plugin is based on).

I like the keyboard shortcut functionality provided by these quite much - however it should be noted that certain keyboard combinations may trigger (or the user may expect them to trigger) certain actions in a particular browser.

E.g. You can capture a `[CTRL] + [A]` keyboard combination, but if you block this from selecting all the text - I can see the user being quite aggravated.